# How to go about creating temporary authentication for a website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, browser

I'm new to authentication with websites, and I've been doing a lot of reading on the different kinds of user authentication (for example session vs token authentication) you can use. However, a lot of it seems more than what I need, and I'm not sure which ones will be suitable for my cause.

My idea is to generate temporary user accounts and passwords that will expire after the first use. I want this integrated with my website, so they have one chance to view restricted pages, after which they will not allowed access to those parts again (unless provided with new credentials).

Any direction in the right step will be appreciated.

Update: I'm using Javascript(Node) as my server side language

Comment: Which server side language are you using?

Comment: @Nitin I'm using JavaScript(Node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session-based authentication is actually incredibly lightweight if you're using a Node backend, due to most (if not all) webserver libraries supporting "middleware", which modify requests before they hit your route functions. The Express-compatable middleware [client-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) is fantastic for this, and I used it previously in a project with great success. It adds a cookie on the first request a user makes to your site which identifies them, and if at some point they log in, you can flag that session as authenticated, store session information, and other data related to them specifically.

Assuming you want both login & logout, the simplest way would to be to use POSTs over HTTPS to `login` & `logout` routes. Inside of the resolution for the login route, you would simply "mark for deletion" inside whatever database you're working with.

An example might look like this:

```
var app = express();

function authenticate(user, pw){
    //do your application specific login verification here
}

function deleteAccount(user){
    //do your application specific user removal here
}

app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret : "YOUR-SECRET-KEY-HERE"
    cookieName : "Session"
    //any other desired config options go here
})

app.post("/login", function(req, res){
    var user = req.body.user;
    var pw = req.body.pw;
    req.Session.isAuthenticated = authenticate(user, pw)
    if(req.Session.isAuthenticated){
        markForDeletion(user, pw);
    }
    res.write("logged in as: " + user);
    res.end();
});
app.post("/logout", function(req, res){
    deleteAccount(req.Session.username);
    req.Session.username = "";
    req.Session.isAuthenticated = false;
    res.write("logged out!");
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank! This is a great start!